# Return the number of times that the string "hi" appears anywhere in the given string -- Python codingbat problem

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop

I'm aware that I can use the .count() function for this, but I tried to do this with a for loop and I keep getting a compile error in line 6. Does anyone see what's wrong with this code and why it wouldn't give the same output? Thanks in advance!

```
def count_hi(string):
# Create an empty list to add to
  num_hi = []
  # for every index in string , if the character is h and the next is i, 
  # add element to list
  for index in string:
    if string[index] == 'h' AND string[index + 1] == 'i':
      num_hi.append('hi found')
  return len(num_hi) # return length of list
```

Comment: python is case sensitive. use `and` not `AND`

Comment: Two issues I found. `AND` should be lowercase `and`. And your for loop is looping over the elements, not the indexes, so `index` is a character, for example `'h`'. Instead of `for index in string`, use `for index in range(len(string))`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)?

```
def count_hi(string):
    return string.count('hi')
```

Fix for your code:

```
def count_hi(string):
    count = 0
    for i in range(1, len(string)):
        if string[i - 1] == 'h' and string[i] == 'i':
            count += 1
    return count
```

1. Python is case sensitive, not <s>`AND`</s> but `and`.
2. Appending to list and counting it is a lot of overhead, you should just use a variable and increment it every time you find `hi`.
3. Instead of enumerate, you can use `range` to start from index `1` and check your string from `i - 1` and `1`. Avoids another check.
4. I'd prefer the previous solution using `.count()`. Why to write code when there is a built-in method for you?

Answer (score 1):

**See [Harshal Parekh's Asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61579156/8627992), it provides a better analysis and explanation.**

When you iterate over a string, you're not iterating over indexes, but over the letters themselves. A quick fix for this could be:

```
def count_hi(string):
  num_hi = []
  # for every index in string , if the character is h and the next is i, add element to list
  for index, _character in enumerate(string):
    if index == len(string) - 1:
      break  # on the last one, you'd get an index error.
    if string[index] == 'h' and string[index + 1] == 'i':  # "and", not "AND"
      num_hi.append('hi found')
  return len(num_hi) # return length of list
```

Comment: While your solution answers the question, it is missing some helpful points that can help the OP. Like is appending to a list and counting the elements a right approach for this problem? Is your check to break necessary (we can start iterating from index 1)? Is this a pythonic way of counting substrings in a string?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use the builtin collection module.

```
from collections import Counter

def count_hi(string):
    counts = Counter(string.split())
    return print(counts['hi'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it should do the trick.

```
def count_hi(str):
      counter = 0
      str.lower()
      str.replace(' ', '')
      for i in range(0, len(str)-1):
        if str[i] == 'h' and str[i+1] == 'i':
          counter += 1
      return counter
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
def count_hi(str):
  sum = 0
  for i in range(len(str)-1):
    if str[i:(i+2)] == "hi":
      sum += 1
  return sum
```

Comment: You can try commenting your solution so other people understand it. I say this because this is a non-pythonic answer more closely resembling how this same problem would be solved in other languages where things like return s.count('hi') are not available or encouraged.